# How can I import an external CSS to react file?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have been searching for over an hour on how to connect an external CSS file to my NavBar.js file for my first website. I am receiving the below error and have tried multiple solutions and am still receiving an error.

```
Module not found: Can't resolve './components/layouts/NavbarStyles.css'
```

In my dependencies, I have installed css loader and styles loader:

```
"dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
"css-loader": "^3.4.0",
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"react-scripts": "3.3.0"


"devDependencies": {
"style-loader": "^1.1.2"
```

And I have added a module in my webpack.config.js (It's around line 330. In some videos I saw, the webpack file was not this long)

```
 module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        }, ],
    },
```

Imports:

```
import React from 'react'
import './components/layouts/NavbarStyles.css';
```

My files:
/src/components/layouts/NavbarStyles.css

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I updated my imports on my navbar.js file to: './src/components/layouts/Navbarstyles.css';

I also updated the module in the webpack like Naman Vyas mentioned below and I added the CSS href to the HTML file like Pradip said and I am still receiving an error: `Module not found: Can't resolve './src/components/layouts/NavbarStyles.css'`

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: try to add file like this: { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }

Comment: add css link into index.html file which is placed inside the  public folder

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import './src/components/layouts/NavBarStyles.css';
```

---

```
    module: {
            rules: [{
                    test: /\.css$/,
                     use: [
                              'style-loader',
                              'css-loader'
                          ]
                     }, ],
             },
```

---

Remove i from above code after /.css$/

---

try to copy paste this code
or check css file path again